# Toad Data Point to export sql statement from Oracle to Sql Server?

Tags: toad, toad-data-point

How can I export data from an Oracle database to a sql server database using Toad Data Point 3.8?

---

We have a remote Oracle database, and I need to export data from that DB to a sql server database. It's the same thing as the sql server Import/Export utility, but using Toad Data Point. I have read-only access to the remote Oracle DB, but I have owner access to the local sql server DB.

What I've tried:
I was looking at this [Toad link](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/b/weblog/archive/2015/10/29/the-easiest-way-to-copy-table-data-from-one-schema-database-to-another-using-toad) but I don't have a `Schema Browser`; I only have and "Object Explorer". I right-click on the table, but I don't see the option "Copy Data to Another Schema".

I then tried right-clicking table and "Export Wizard", but I don't see an option to export to another database. All the options are to hard file (sql script, CSV, tab-delimited, etc). I would choose "Sql Script" but there's so much data that the script would just be enormous.

Finally, I tried "Data Export Wizard" and I don't see an option to export to a sql server database. So I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the Import Wizard, from the Oracle DB to the SQL Server DB. Very simple.